# spark - where dataframe is defined in scala source code

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Im trying to find DataFrame class definition in scala source code not in pyspark.

There is some files like DataFrameReader, DataFrameWriter, Dataset But not DataFrame.

I have found some directories such as spark/sql, spark/core.

Comment: It is right there in the [documentation of the `org.apache.spark.sql` package](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.package@DataFrame=org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]). There is a link to the source file itself right under the package description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DataFrame is just a Dataset[Row] and is a type alias:

```scala
type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/50538600ec972469338370f7e2d3674ca8b3c389/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/package.scala#L46